# How can one adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, camera

I use iPhone 11 mini with iOS 15. I don't see where to adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture:

[image]

How can one adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture with an iPhone?

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.